# Gmail API- Metadata scope does not support 'q' parameter

Tags: api, google-api, metadata, gmail-api, google-apis-explorer

I'm trying to use Gmail API for my web app. What I want is get messages which has attachment file and I'm following [this tutoral](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list).

The problem is when I use 'q' parameter, it return the error: `Metadata scope does not support 'q' parameter`

[My request URL](https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=%22has:attachment%22)

Note: My authorize scopes are:

- https://mail.google.com/
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message occurs when `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata` is included in the scopes. But in your scopes, it is not used. So please confirm the following points again.

- If the refresh token is retrieved in your script, please remove it and authorize again using the scopes without `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata`.
- If you use Google APIs Explorer, please remove Google APIs Explorer at https://myaccount.google.com/permissions.

  - Please login and remove it.

After you did above, please use the API of endpoint by authorizing using the scopes without `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata`.

If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's worked. The reason is I allowed gmail.metadata in the old scope, and after I removed it in Google APIs Explorer, the authorize will ask permission again.

Comment: @Phat Le I'm glad your problem was solved. I had also had the same situation.

Comment: still working, thanks. Issue is "In Progress" from Google : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62062921

Comment: @Saayeed M Daawoud About `not working for me!`, I apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. But, I would like to support you. So, can you post your question as a new question by including more information to correctly understand `not working for me!`? By this, it will help users think of a solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @Tanaike thanks for ur response that is my question https://stackoverflow.com/q/78124149/11287483

Comment: @Saayeed M Daawoud Thank you for your response.