# Gmail Api - Metadata scope does not support 'q' parameter

Tags: flutter, dart, oauth-2.0, google-api, gmail-api

I'm trying to use Gmail API for my Flutter app. I'm going to make a list of unread messages that became from someone
so as API References, I'm using this code

```
    var url = Uri.https(EndPoints.gmailBaseUrl, EndPoints.listUnredMessages, {'labelIds': 'UNREAD', 'q' : 'from:Daniel Agbemava'});
// static const String gmailBaseUrl = 'gmail.googleapis.com';
//  static const String listUnredMessages = '/gmail/v1/users/me/messages';
    var request = http.Request('GET', url,);
    request.headers.addAll(authHeaders!);
    http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();
    Map<String, dynamic> jsonResponse = jsonDecode(await response.stream.bytesToString());
    log(jsonResponse.toString());
```

as the reference and this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48699127/11287483) i removed `Google APIs Explorer` from premissions and this my new scope

```
static const List<String> scopes = <String>[
    'https://mail.google.com/',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly',
  ];
```

so I went to make a new OAuth and then request the one that I need
but I get this response error

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: DetailedApiRequestError(status: 403, message: Metadata scope does not support 'q' parameter)
```

how to solve it?